# pdflatexmk compiles \glossaries fine but neglects \glsaddall

Tags: glossaries, latexmk

I'm using TeXShop and the pdflatexmk script. When I link at least one entry of the glossary with `\gls{label}` the glossary compiles fine and all works well (working code example).
However I want to use the `\glsaddall` command such that I don't have to link to all glossary entries. Unfortunately pdflatexmk neglects this option (malfunctioning code example). Why does it do that?

I know I can run the makeglossaries command in the terminal, but I would rather have it work with pdflatexmk. How can I solve this? Is there a newer pdflatexmk script that addresses this issue?

A working example is shown below.

### Working code: mentioning at least one glossary item with \gls{label}:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,final]{report}
\usepackage[toc, nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\tableofcontents
\printglossaries

\chapter{Chapatare Uno}
\newglossaryentry{One}
{name=One, description={First number after zero}}
Body text for chapter one mentioning the glossary item \gls{One}

\chapter{Chapter Deux}
\newglossaryentry{Open}
{name=Open, description={Opposite of closed}}
Body text for chapter two mentioning the glossary item \gls{Open}

\end{document}
```

### Malfunctioning code: using \glsaddall to print entries without mention

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,final]{report}
\usepackage[toc, nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\tableofcontents
\glsaddall
\printglossaries

\chapter{Chapatare Uno}
\newglossaryentry{One}
{name=One, description={First number after zero}}
Body text for chapter one NOT mentioning the glossary item 

\chapter{Chapter Deux}
\newglossaryentry{Open}
{name=Open, description={Opposite of closed}}
Body text for chapter two NOT mentioning the glossary item

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the glossary entry definitions *before* issuing `\glsaddall`, and make sure that `latexmk` knows how to deal with glossaries. There is an [example file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexmk/example_rcfiles/glossary_latexmkrc) in the package that shows what you should add to your `~/.latexmkrc` setting file.

All in all,

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,final]{report}
\usepackage[toc, nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{One}
{name=One, description={First number after zero}}
\newglossaryentry{Open}
{name=Open, description={Opposite of closed}}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\tableofcontents
\glsaddall
\printglossaries

\chapter{Chapatare Uno}
Body text for chapter one NOT mentioning the glossary item

\chapter{Chapter Deux}
Body text for chapter two NOT mentioning the glossary item

\end{document}
```

and

```
add_cus_dep( 'glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglo2gls' );
sub makeglo2gls {
    system("makeindex -s \"$_[0].ist\" -t \"$_[0].glg\" -o \"$_[0].gls\" \"$_[0].glo\"" );
}
```

**or**

```
add_cus_dep( 'glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglossaries' );
sub makeglossaries {
   system( "makeglossaries \"$_[0]\"" );
}
```

in `~/.latexmkrc` resolves your problem.

Comment: It works, thank you for the solution. It puzzles me though why the default latexmk script (without the `makeglossaries` sub) compiles the glossary fine when I use `\gls{label}`.  Doesn't that indicate that it already knows how to compile glossaries?

Comment: @BartArondson Maybe you have a rule already in `latexmkrc`? Or you have a `.gls` file around from some manual run of `makeindex`? I tested this: with a clean folder (only the tex file), and a vanilla `latexmk` (without the sub), I never get a `.gls` file, regardless what is in the tex file.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand it now. With the vanilla `latexmkrc` I can put the glossary entry definitions in the body (as I did originally), but then it only works when I use `\gls{label}` in the body as well. If I don't use `\gls{label}` and try to use `\glsaddall` no glossary is printed. But when I put the entry definitions *before* `\glsaddall` (as you suggested) and run the vanilla `latexmkrc` it works. So adding the sub is not necessary for the `latexmkrc` script bundled with TexShop. My problem was that I didn't place the glossary entry definitions before calling `\glsaddall`.